# Why is this async arrow function valid JS syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I've seen async functions and arrow functions before but none that look like this:

```
    load: async () => {
        // Load app..
        await App.loadWeb3()
        await App.loadAccount()
    },
```

My question is why is this valid syntax, and is there a resource I can learn more about it? I already tried looking through the Mozilla documentation under async and arrow functions.

If I were to guess how to do it I would probably come up with the following, which are (obviously) incorrect

```
    async func load = () => {
        // Load app..
        await App.loadWeb3()
        await App.loadAccount()
    },
```

I thought that async was supposed to be declared before the function as well as using the func keyword

Comment: Arrow functions don't have names, other than the identifier/property they may happen to be assigned to. So `() => { ...` is an expression that's an arrow function, as is `async () => { ...`

Comment: This is just a property in an [object initializer](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). This has nothing to do with async functions, specifically.